# How to remove event listeners attached with onclick

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I need a way to remove event listeners attached with `onclick="func()"` in javascript

below is sample code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <script>
  function f1(){
      alert("f1");
  }
  function f2(){
      alert("f2");
      document.getElementById("b1").removeEventListener("click",f1);
  }
  </script>
  <button id="b1" type="button" onclick="f1()">B1</button>
  <button id="b2" type="button" onclick="f2()">B2</button>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another blank listener to it as

```
document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
     return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just set the `onclick` property of the element to `null`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    function f1() {
      alert("f1");
    }

    function f2() {
      alert("f2");
      document.getElementById("b1").onclick = null
    }
  </script>
  <button id="b1" type="button" onclick="f1()">B1</button>
  <button id="b2" type="button" onclick="f2()">B2</button>

</body>

</html>
```

This is because when you do `onclick="f1()"`, the browser creates a new function for you, somewhat (but not entirely) equivalent to this:

```
elem.onclick = new Function("event", "f1()")
```

Which gives you a function, something like this:

```
elem.onclick = function(event) {
  f1()
}
```

So setting that property to `null` simply overwrites the assigned function, setting it back to its default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it:

```
document.getElementById("b1").removeEventListener("click",f1);
```

for it:

```
document.getElementById("b1").onclick = null;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <script>
  function f1(){
      alert("f1");
  }
  function f2(){
      alert("f2");
      document.getElementById("b1").onclick = null;
  }
  </script>
  <button id="b1" type="button" onclick="f1()">B1</button>
  <button id="b2" type="button" onclick="f2()">B2</button>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the onclick to null works fine, but you might notice if you inspect the DOM your onclick is still there.

So another way is to use `removeAttribute`

eg.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <script>
  function f1(){
    alert("f1");
  }
  function f2(){
    alert("f2");
    document.getElementById("b1").
      removeAttribute("onclick");
  }
  </script>
  <button id="b1" type="button" onclick="f1()">B1</button>
  <button id="b2" type="button" onclick="f2()">B2</button>
 
  </body>
</html>
```